# Unable to connect matplot graph to database in Django

Tags: django, matplotlib, filter, aggregate-functions

I would be very grateful for any help to my problem:

**Goal:**

I am trying to plot a matplot pie chart with data from my sqlite database.

I achieved to plot a simple pie chart on my webpage (without using the database).

**My problem:**

In order to connect the data from my database, I used the *filter()* and *aggregate()* methods. 
On the webpage the plot is not loading (I only receive an image symbol).

**What I want to plot:**

In my plot I want to display the sum of the costs(spendings) in each category as a pie plot.

Here is my code:

**models.py:**

```
CHOICES = (
    ('rent', 'Rent'), 
    ('grocery', 'Grocery'), 
    ('shopping', 'Shopping'), 
    ('gym', 'Gym'), 
    ('phone', 'Phone'), 
    ('freetime', 'Freetime'), 
    ('other', 'Other')
)

class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="new_spending", null=True)   

    expense_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CHOICES)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from django.db.models import Sum
from .models import UserDetails
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def statistics(request):
    return render(request, "budget_app/statistics.html")

def test_plot(request):  

    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')  


#The problem must lie here:  

    wedges = [UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='rent').aggregate(Sum('cost')),
    UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='grocery').aggregate(Sum('cost')),
    UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='shopping').aggregate(Sum('cost')),
    UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='gym').aggregate(Sum('cost')),
    UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='phone').aggregate(Sum('cost')),
    UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='freetime').aggregate(Sum('cost')),
    UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='other').aggregate(Sum('cost'))]


    # wedges = []
    #for element in UserDetails.category:
     #   wedges.append(UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category=element).aggregate(Sum('cost'))

    labels = ['rent', 'grocery', 'shopping', 'gym', 'phone', 'freetime', 'other']    
    ax.pie(wedges, labels=labels, colors=['b', 'r', 'g', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'])
    ax.legend(wedges, labels=labels, title='legend title', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))
    ax.set_title('Spending statistics per category')
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    response=HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpg")
    canvas.print_jpg(response)
    return response
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('statistics/', views.statistics, name='statistics'),
path('test_plot/', views.test_plot, name='test_plot'),
]
```

**statistics.html:**

```
{% extends 'budget_app/budget_base.html' %}

{% block title %}Statistics{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}  

<body>
    <h2>Your spending statistics:</h2>
    </br>
</br>
    <img src="/budget_app/test_plot/" width="600px" />
</body>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if the aggregate function is what you want to use here - it outputs a dict. I would use the sum of  the flattened values_list here.

Comment: Thank you for your tipp! I managed to access the dict values by doing: ```wedges = [UserDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user, category='rent').aggregate(suma=Sum('cost'))['suma']  or 0.00, ...]```